# Subcommand flags (options)

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a CLI application that will accept few arguments based on the subcommand by using the standard flag package. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("start application\n")

    fooCmd := flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    fooName := fooCmd.String("name", "", "name")

    barCmd := flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
    barLevel := barCmd.Int("level", 0, "level")

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("expected 'foo' or 'bar' subcommands")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "foo":
        fooCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("  name:", *fooName)
    case "bar":
        barCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("  level:", *barLevel)
    default:
        fmt.Println("expected 'foo' or 'bar' subcommands")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

and by calling it with:

```
$ ./main foo -name=test
```

It's working as expected.

The issue is that I want to have another flag (let's say `--loglevel=Debug`) which should be called for any of those subcommands (`foo/bar`), something like:

```
$ ./main foo -name=test -loglevel=debug
```

One option would be to create the same flag (`loglevel`) for any of those subcommands, but I just wonder is there any other way to achieve this without duplicating the code?
In my case, I have about 6 subcommands and 4 "general" flags.

Answer (score 1):

That is why I prefer using a third-party library, rather than the default flags package.
For, instance, with [`alecthomas/kong`](https://github.com/alecthomas/kong/blob/d0c0180cecfd46203f91b16795cd70156a89b4ba/kong_test.go#L173-L187):

```golang
func TestPropagatedFlags(t *testing.T) {
    var cli struct {
        Flag1    string
        Command1 struct {
            Flag2    bool
            Command2 struct{} `kong:"cmd"`
        } `kong:"cmd"`
    }

    parser := mustNew(t, &cli)
    _, err := parser.Parse([]string{"command-1", "command-2", "--flag-2", "--flag-1=moo"})
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.Equal(t, "moo", cli.Flag1)
    require.Equal(t, true, cli.Command1.Flag2)
}
```

Flag1 is global, and would apply to any subcommand.